# How to connect signals between scenes?

Tags: signals, game-development, gdscript, godot4

In my project I can't connect signals between different scenes, and even in a test project it doesn't work.
Test project

scene:lol

```
`extends Node2D

signal an_awesome_signal

func an_awesome_function():
    emit_signal('an_awesome_signal', 'data that the listeners receive')

func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        an_awesome_function()`
```

scene:yyy

```
`extends Node2D

func _on_An_awesome_signal(data):
    print(data)

func _ready():
    var node = get_tree().get_root().find_node("lol",true,false)
    node.an_awesome_signal.connect(_on_An_awesome_signal)
```

`

Main project.

scene: player

`

```
func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event.is_action_pressed("shoot"):
        shoot()
    
    
func shoot():
    print("shoot")
    var bullet_instaniate = bullet.instantiate()
    var direction = gun_direction.global_position - end_of_gun.global_position
        emit_signal("player_fired_bullet",bullet_instaniate,end_of_gun.global_position,direction)`
```

scene: world

`extends Node2D

@export var bullet = preload("res://bullet.tscn")

```
func _ready():
    var playernode = get_tree().get__root().find_node("player",true,false)
    playernode.player_fired_bullet.connect(handle_bullet_spawned)

func handle_bullet_spawned(bullet, position, direction):
    print("bullet spawned")
    add_child(bullet)
    bullet.global_position = position
    bullet.set_direction = direction`
```

Node: BulletManager (in the "world" scene)

` extends Node2D

```
func handle_bullet_spawned(bullet, position, direction):
    add_child(bullet)
    bullet.global_position = position
    bullet.set_direction = direction`
```

Comment: Are you getting errors?